# Setting state with Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an input form for users to input multiple options, which stores that as an array of "essentials" in an object in state. Currently, they have to enter it separated by commas, like this: "item one,item two, item three". This is working perfectly, and the code for the input TextField looks like this:

```
        <TextField
          name="essentials"
          label="Essentials (comma separated)"
          fullWidth
          onChange={(e) =>
            setPotluckData({
              ...potluckData,
              essentials: e.target.value.split(","),
            })
          }
        />
```

However, I would like to use the Material UI Autocomplete function so that the items turn into tags (just like when you're adding tags at the bottom of the Stack Overflow question page!). Here's a picture of the UX - which aesthetically is exactly what I'm after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZRz.png

However, I can't make it pass all of the items to the "essentials" field of the object. The closest I've gotten is that it passes the final tag - so in the example above, it would only pass "item three" when it creates the new object. Here's what the code for that looks like:

```
          <Autocomplete
            multiple
            id="tags-standard"
            options={Examples.map((option) => option.title)}
            freeSolo
            renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
              value.map((option, index) => (
                <Chip
                  variant="standard"
                  label={option}
                  {...getTagProps({ index })}
                />
              ))
            }

            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="standard"
                name="Essentials"
                label="Essentials"
                margin="normal"
                placeholder="Essentials"
                value={potluckData.essentials}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setPotluckData({
                    ...potluckData,
                    essentials: e.target.value,
                  })
                }
              />
            )}
          />
```

So in the original, the object it creates would end up with a field like this: `essentials: ["item one", "item two", "item three"]`
But the Autocomplete example would just be `essentials: ["item three"]`

Any ideas??

Comment: Have you considered this package? https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input

Comment: @KevinAshworth that works a charm!! Thanks so much - guess I was making it all a lot more complicated for myself than I needed to

Comment: You are welcome! I've found that package very handy.